# past and present tense confusion

Tags: present-tense, grammaticality-in-context, formal-language, email

It's about an e-mail.

> - Please be **advise** that if the port is the damage, we need to replace the MB.
> - Please be **advised** that if the port is damaged, we need to replace the MB.

Answer (score 1):

The second one seems more natural, since the first seems to identify the port with the damage. As far as the tense (and mood, and so forth), the sentences both have two present-tense verbs. Some people might prefer "will need" instead of "need," but it is not very important. I do not see any past-tense conjugations.

Answer (score 1):

The first option is incorrect. The phrase "be advised" means "know this" and would be followed by the information you want the recipient to know. "Be advise" does not make sense at all

Then "if the port is the damage" does not make sense either. "The damage" is a phrase that can be used ("The damage to my car was severe"), but it refers to the more general idea of damage and not to a specific item or part that was damaged. You could say "if the damaged part is the port" or "if the port is the damaged part", but not "if the port is the damage".

In summary, option 2 is grammatically correct. You could also say:

> Please be advised that if the port is the damaged part, we need to replace the MB.

But I think option 2 is even better than this because it is more flexible in allowing for the fact that other parts may be damaged as well, and not only the port.